# LUA: String split after number of characters

Tags: lua

I have a 18 digit number, and would like to split it into 2 portions( 9 digits each). Could you advice me about a way to go about it?

I tried the string.split and divide it with string.len but that doesn't seem to work.

Eg: number = 45698745896547854

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is no string.split and you cannot divide a string either. if you don't know what you can do with a string or to answer most other questions, just refer to the manual https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/

Comment: `group9 = '('.. ('%d'):rep(9) .. ')'; string.match(number, group9 .. group9 )`

Comment: thanks greatwolf...

Answer (score 5):

I did some thinking, and was able to solve it this way:

```
stringOne = string.sub(IHINumber, 1, 9)
stringTwo = string.sub(IHINumber, 10, 18)
```

Comment: if s has the number as string: a,b=s:sub(1,9),s:sub(-9)